# Visual Studio 2015 Node.js tools npm version

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015, joyent, node.js-tools

I would like to use the latest npm within Visual Studio 2015. I've installed Joyent Node from the Visual Studio installer. I understand one can install Node.js seperately but we seem to have issues with that so we are trying to do things the "Microsoft Way". I have also installed the Node.js Tools 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015. Within the node.js interactive window within Visual Studio, running .npm gives me the following:

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\MyUsername\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
npm@2.7.4 C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm
 successfully completed
```

However, if I use the "Node.js command prompt" and run:

```
npm -g install npm
```

It updates npm and running npm command I get the following:

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\MyUsername\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.8.0 C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```

If I got back to Visual Studio 2015 Node.js Interactive Window and run .npm, I see the version hasn't changed, even with a VS restart. However, I had a long filename issue as reported by other users and not had the issue so I believe that npm 3.8.0 is actually being used but I can't be sure. How can I get Visual Studio 2015 to use the latest npm so I can avoid the long file name problem? Does the Node.js Interactive Window have any relevance here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools` and add path to your node install. Then move it up in the list of dependencies.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I followed advice regarding this already. This is what's in my list in order:
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs, .\node_modules\.bin, $(PATH), $(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External, $(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git

Answer (score 0):

Running npm-windows-upgrade within the Node.js command prompt and adding it with the path option with the path output in Visual Studio 2015 (above) fixed it for me.

http://www.triplet.fi/blog/npm-3-will-bring-brighter-future-for-windows-users/

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade